# Need help on the tar command

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Have got a problem executing the command as below:

```
tar -xvf arch.tar.gz -s '/^bundle//'
```

Could be the

```
-s '/^bundle//'
```

is a problem as I've got errors like:

```
$ tar -xvf arch.tar.gz -s '/^bundle//'
tar: /^bundle: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The tried to run the command under Cygwin/Win10.
It's part of the longer script but I'm not sure what was the idea of original author. Archive does include the 'bundle' folder inside... and it's the only first level file there.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Which `tar` is that? (please post answer of `tar --version`)

Comment: -s flag is to sort names to extract to match in archive, check if that makes sense in your program logic if that is required else you can get rid of it and just use tar -xvf arch.tar.gz bundle

Comment: tar (GNU tar) 1.28 Packaged by Cygwin (1.28-1) Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Maybe you are speaking abount tar `transform` or `xform` option: `tar -zxvf arch.tar.gz '--xform=s+/bundle-+/+' --show-transformed`

Comment: Just want to add the obligatory tar joke https://xkcd.com/1168/. Does anyone not have to read the man page or Google it?

Answer (score 0):

`-s` does not mean to do a substitution, which seems to be how you're trying to use it.  You probably want `--xform='s/^bundle//'`

`-s` has the following entry in the help listing:

> -s, --preserve-order, --same-order
>                               member arguments are listed in the same order as
>                               the files in the archive

With your code it's actually trying to find a file with the name `/^bundle//` which does not exist, even if `bundle` does.  Also, the `--xform` option I gave will rewrite the names of files to strip the string `bundle` from the front.  If you are just trying to not extract the file `bundle` you would want the flag `--exclude='bundle'`

In this case, if `bundle` is a top level directory in the archive, and it's the only one, you could also use the flag `--strip-components=1`, though this would get rid of all the top level directories, so might not be exactly what you want depending on your archive

Comment: The problem is that I'm not an author of the line given ... It's written as it is, but it's not working... The only idea I have is that the goal was to extract folders structure but without first /bundle/ folder ...

Comment: @PaulPaku I just updated my answer to show how to do that

Comment: I think the idea was to extract ALL files but first remove the top folder named /bundle/. So /bundle/1/* and /bundle/2/* would be extracted into /1/* and /2/* files/folders.

Comment: @PaulPaku I also just updated the answer with another option that might help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

Problem solved other, then 'tar', way but for those who may be interested here is the answer I have found on the web:

If you are developing on Linux, or using GNU tar, this command should work:

```
tar -xvf arch.tar.gz --transform 's|^bundle/||'
```

For Mac or BSD-based operating systems:

```
tar -xvf arch.tar.gz -s '/^bundle//'
```

Yes, the idea was to remove the /bundle/ folder from files paths.

Comment: how to do this in windows 10. I'm getting bundle not found